# Unity generates OBB and integrates it into Android native

Tags: unity-game-engine

I recently encountered a problem that unity subcontracts and integrates them into Android native projects to read configuration in OBB

The specific performance is that the `path = $"{application. Streamingassetspath} / config ﹤ plat. JSON"` is not the same.

There is a subcontracting that can be used normally. The read path is `jar: File: / / / storage / simulated / 0 / Android / OBB / com.locojoy.restart/main.packagename.obb! / assets / config ﹤ plat.json`

Other subcontracts are `jar: File: / / / data / APP / packagename-onkjhz6o-5jps0izjrj4wa = = / base. APK! / assets / config_plat. JSON`

What's the reason? It's been a long time！！！

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the OBB package. There is a 0kb file to configure the file name to Android: name = "unity. Build ID"

android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />

We can solve the problem